# How to unwrapResult for all dispatched actions with redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux-toolkit and would like to cut down on code duplication by not having to call `unwrapResult` after every dispatched asynchronous action. I am handling errors for all dispatched actions via displaying a toast message to the user so I'd need to unwrap according to redux-toolkit [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk).

Ideally, I'd like to wrap the dispatch function returned from the `useDispatch()` function from react-redux using a hook something like the following...

```
// Example of wrapped dispatch function
function SomeComponent() {
  const dispatch = useWrappedAppDispatch()

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() =>
        dispatch(myAsyncAction())
          .catch((_err) =>
            toast("Error processing action")
          )
      }
    ></button>
  )
}
```

```js
// configureStore.ts
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist"
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage"

import { logger } from "../middleware/logger"
import rootReducer from "./reducer"

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
      immutableCheck: false,
    }).concat(logger),
})

export { store }

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>

export interface GetState {
  getState: () => RootState
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. To do this we will create a custom hook `useAppDispatchUnwrap` and return a wrapped redux-toolkit function which will call `unwrapResult` on all dispatched actions. Just note that by unwrapping all dispatched actions you have to handle any exceptions that are thrown otherwise the app will crash due to uncaught exceptions.

```js
// useAppDispatchUnwrap.ts
import { AsyncThunkAction, unwrapResult } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { AppDispatch, useAppDispatch } from "../store/config/configureStore"

export default function useAppDispatchUnwrap() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

  async function dispatchUnwrapped<R extends any>(
    action: AsyncThunkAction<R, any, any>
  ): Promise<R> {
    return dispatch(action).then(unwrapResult)
  }

  return dispatchUnwrapped
}
```

```js
// configureStore.ts
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist"
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage"

import { logger } from "../middleware/logger"
import rootReducer from "./reducer"

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
      immutableCheck: false,
    }).concat(logger),
})

export { store }

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>

export interface GetState {
  getState: () => RootState
}
```

```js
// Example of using wrapped dispatch function
import useAppDispatchUnwrap from "./useAppDispatchUnwrap";

function SomeComponent() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatchUnwrap();

  // All dispatched actions are now automatically unwrapped using redux-toolkit "unwrapResult" function.
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() =>
        dispatch(myAsyncAction())
          .catch((_err) =>
            toast("Error processing action")
          )
      }
    ></button>
  )
}
```